# Received "SQLSTATE[42000]: LIMIT ERROR" when using MySQL via PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I spent quite a bit of time researching, could not get it resolve. Hence seeking expert advice.

Exact Error:

> Error fetching Data: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''LIMIT 0,10''

Here is my SQL :

```
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage; 

try
{
  $sql2 = 'SELECT CASE_JOB_TITLE, STATUS, CASE_WAGE  
           FROM EMPLOYEE
           WHERE LCA_CASE_EMPLOYER_NAME like "%MICROSOFT CORPORATION%" 
           ORDER BY         LCA_CASE_NUMBER ASC :limit';

  $sth2 =$pdo->prepare($sql2);
  $sth2->bindParam(':limit',$limit );
  $result2 = $sth2->execute();


}
```

Where am I going wrong?  If I use the same query in SQL Editor it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure you can use a bound parameter for LIMIT? It looks like it's being wrapped in quotes, from the error message; so I suspect you can't do it this way.

Comment: Maybe it's an MySQL easter egg, and it throws out any searches for "MICROSOFT CORPORATION"?

Comment: (I think @Andrew is right, and furthermore you can't inject "LIMIT 20" either; it defeats the purpose of parameterisation).

Comment: I think andrewsi and halfer are right. I have tried with just numbers, it worked. It defies the purpose of bind and prepare to avoid SQL Injection attacks.  Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing the bind with string. I used the final set of code is ORDER BY LCA_CASE_NUMBER ASC LIMIT :limitFrom,40'; $sth2 =$pdo->prepare($sql2); $sth2->bindParam(':limitFrom –

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Didn't see your first part. Try this:

It should look like:

```
$limit = ($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage;

$sql2 = 'SELECT CASE_JOB_TITLE, STATUS, CASE_WAGE  
           FROM EMPLOYEE
           WHERE LCA_CASE_EMPLOYER_NAME like "%MICROSOFT CORPORATION%" 
           ORDER BY         LCA_CASE_NUMBER ASC LIMIT :limit';
```

Comment: No Luck, I tried the above, but still error. The error I get is : Error fetching Data: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0,10'' at line 4

Comment: Thanks for reply. I solved it by removing the bind with string. I used the final set of code is ORDER BY LCA_CASE_NUMBER ASC LIMIT :limitFrom,40';
  $sth2 =$pdo->prepare($sql2);
  $sth2->bindParam(':limitFrom